# Google sheet - compare items based on another dataset and get the one with max value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I have a series of words in a column A, each associated with a certain number/score.

After this table of words/score, I have lines where I have values of these words and I run a contest and must get the item with the highest score.

Let's make this simple with this example:

[image]

Here my quesiton is about getting the blue value inside `E8`. That is: how to create a fomula which takes analyzes the contender of line 8 which are `"word4 word5"`, `"word1 word2"`, and `"word2 word6"` and for each of them goes on the column A to find it and find their associated score. And then put the name with the highest score on `E8`.

Note there here is a special attention for `D7` which is `"word2 word6"` because there won't be a match on column A.

You'll see below the structure of my data and table: note that there I need to keep the comparison between strings/words on line 8 (and below) inside the column B, C, D and E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(B8:D8), 
 A2:F7, 6, 0), ))), {ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(B8:D8), 
 A2:F7, 6, 0), )), TRANSPOSE(B8:D8)}, 2, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: actually it does not work: i'll edit my question to give you an example where your formula fails: if there is another field with the same value

Comment: as you can see, i added a row 'word9 word11' which coincidentally has the same score as 'word4 word5' and in the blue cell, E8 I should get 'word4 word5', but with your fomula i get the wrong result= i get 'word9 word11'

Comment: @Mathieu at least you see where your question failed :) answer updated...

Comment: :) yes i see now. Will try in abt one hour when i get back home. Tx again